# How to find the roots of the following equation:

Tags: roots

How to find the roots of the following equation:

$10.9-11.4 x^2+0.5 *\ln (17 x)=0 \ $ using computer program or else .

I need the roots only  but I have no idea to find the roots. **Can anyone help me with roots of the above equation .**

Comment: according to wolframalpha the only root is about 1.04

Comment: Now, how can you refine (get more decimals of) this root ? Try dichotomy, or (much better) Newton's method.

Comment: There is another root near $2\cdot 10^{-11}$

Comment: @Vasya Once more, Wolfram Alpha is not trustable (in fact, you guess there can exist a second root when looking at the graphical representation)

Comment: Well, using the command "roots" I found both roots, moreover, using the original equation a picture with two points appeared (but only one root was mentioned)

Comment: @JeanMarie As a programmer, I know all too well that human brain cannot be replaced by a machine. My first thought was that there should be two roots because of $x^2$

Comment: The second derivate is negative for all $x>0$, hence we cannot have more than $2$ real roots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need numerical methods (Apparantly, mathworld does not find a closed-form-solution, so the Lambert-W-function seems to be useless here). The two roots are (calculated with PARI/GP)

```
? solve(x=2*10^(-11),2.01*10^(-11),10.9-11.4*x^2+0.5*log(17*x))
%4 = 2.004155307311702078727439326 E-11
? solve(x=1,1.1,10.9-11.4*x^2+0.5*log(17*x))
%5 = 1.040257251066025097928117626
?
```

Using the first two derivates should help to prove that there are only two roots.

Comment: On the contrary, in this case Lambert-W-function gives a closed form solution
- see the other answer.

Comment: @g.kov Strange that Wolfram alpha does not find the closed form solution of the concrete function! Note that I formulated "seems" because I had some doubts that Lambert-W does not apply here.

Answer (score 2):

Wolfram Alpha
gives an exact solution 
to
\begin{align}
a+b\,x^k+c\,\ln(d\,x)=0
\end{align}

in terms of [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function):

\begin{align}
x&=\left(\frac{c}{k\,b}\,
\operatorname{W}\left(\frac{k\,b}{c}\,\left(\tfrac1d\,\exp(-\frac{a}{c})\right)^k\right)\right)^{1/k},
\end{align}
which for $a=10.9,\ k=2,\ b=-11.4,\ c=0.5, d=17$
gives two real solutions,

$x_1\approx 2.0041553073117\cdot10^{-11}$ for the branch $\operatorname{W_0}$
and $x_2\approx 1.04025725106996$
for the branch  $\operatorname{W_{-1}}$.

**Edit**

The solution in terms of $W$ can be derived manually as follows:

\begin{align}
a+b\,x^k+c\,\ln(d\,x)
&=0,\\
-k\,\tfrac{a}c-k\,\tfrac{b}c\,x^k+\ln(d^{-k}\,x^{-k})
&=0,\\
\ln\left(\exp(-k\,\tfrac{a}c)\,d^{-k}\,x^{-k}\right)
&=k\,\tfrac{b}c\,x^k
,\\
\exp(-k\,\tfrac{a}c)\,d^{-k}\,x^{-k}\,\ln\left(\exp(-k\,\tfrac{a}c)\,d^{-k}\,x^{-k}\right)
&=k\,\tfrac{b}c\,\exp(-k\,\tfrac{a}c)\,d^{-k}
,\\
\ln\left(\exp(-k\,\tfrac{a}c)\,d^{-k}\,x^{-k}\right)
&=\operatorname{W}(\,\tfrac{b}c\,\exp(-k\,\tfrac{a}c)\,d^{-k})
,\\
\exp(-k\,\tfrac{a}c)\,d^{-k}\,x^{-k}
&=\exp\left(\operatorname{W}(\,\tfrac{b}c\,\exp(-k\,\tfrac{a}c)\,d^{-k})\right)
,\\
\exp(\tfrac{a}c)\,d\,x
&=\exp\left(-\tfrac1k\,\operatorname{W}(\,\tfrac{b}c\,\exp(-k\,\tfrac{a}c)\,d^{-k})\right)
,\\
x&=\tfrac1d\,
\exp\left(-\tfrac1k\,\operatorname{W}(\,\tfrac{b}c\,\exp(-k\,\tfrac{a}c)\,d^{-k})
-\tfrac{a}c
\right)
.
\end{align}

For the given set of constants, the argument of $W$ is negative, but greater than $-\tfrac1e$,
hence there are two real solutions 
corresponding to the branches $W_0$ and $W_{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not use Lambert function, consider the function
$$f(x)=10.9-11.4 x^2+0.5 \,\log (17 x)$$ $$f'(x)=-22.8x+\frac{0.5} x$$ $$f''(x)=-22.8-\frac{0.5} {x^2}$$ So, the first derivative cancels at $x_*$ such that $$x_*=\sqrt{\frac 5 {228}}\approx 0.148087$$ At this point $f(x_*)\approx 11.1116$ and $f''(x_*)<0$. So there are two roots $0 < x_1 <x_*$ and $x_*< x_2$.

The largest root is easy to find by inspection (or graphing). Since it is close to $1$, we could approximate it using Taylor series
$$f(x) =0.5 (\log (17)-1)-{22.3 (x-1)}+O\left((x-1)^2\right)$$ leading to $x_2\approx 1.04110$.

For $x_1$, close to $0$,we have $$f(x)=10.9+ 0.5 *\log (17 x)+O\left(x\right)$$ leading to $x_1\approx 2.00416\times 10^{-11}$.

As you can see, we can get good approximation at the price of solving one linear equation (the first one in $x$, the second one in $\log(x)$.